# Dynamically change color of (List item)TextView in Listview

Tags: android, android-layout, android-listview

I am using a ListView as shown below in filename browse.xml.

```
<ListView
   android:id="@+id/listView1"
   android:layout_width="250dp"
   android:layout_height="match_parent"
   android:layout_alignParentLeft="true"
   android:layout_below="@+id/relativeLayout1" >

</ListView>
```

And I am filling this listView inside onCreate() method as:

```
files1=new ArrayList<String>();
File sdcard=Environment.getExternalStorageDirectory();
files1 =  getListFiles(new File(sdcard.getAbsolutePath()+File.separatorChar)); 
ArrayAdapter<String> fileList =new ArrayAdapter<String>(this, R.layout.row,files1);

setListAdapter(fileList);
```

row.xml is shown below as:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<TextView 
   xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
   android:id="@+id/rowtext"
   android:layout_width="fill_parent"
   android:layout_height="40dp"
   android:textSize="20dp" 
   android:textColor="#000000"   
   android:background="#FFFFFF"/>
```

This whole program is am showing all the files of sdcard at listView and on click of any listitem, am saving that file name into sharedPrefernce..Now I want to change the text color of file name(List items) in the ListView which are there in SharedPrefernce..

**[EDIT]: Here am using ArrayAdapter default constructor to list all the items in a listview**

Pls suggest me something..
Thanks..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

We can change the textcolor dynamically for list item in the getView() of Adapter.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    View row = convertView;

    if (row == null) {
        row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, null);
    }

    TextView listTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowtext);
    listTitle.setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#405478"));

    return listTitle;
}
```

Comment: No but am not using any of the Adapter class

Comment: without using adapter how you are using row.xml for list item

Comment: Am using ArrayAdapter default constructor to add files1 data into row.xml textview to list all the items in ListView

Comment: if you want to set color for text view dynamically in list vew list item you can make adapter class..just create custom adapter for this.

Comment: check this link http://www.ezzylearning.com/tutorial.aspx?tid=1763429&q=customizing-android-listview-items-with-custom-arrayadapter and http://android.vexedlogic.com/2011/04/02/android-lists-listactivity-and-listview-ii-%E2%80%93-custom-adapter-and-list-item-view/

Answer (score 2):

**FIRST**

Take one

```
ArrayList<boolean> saved = new ArrayList<boolean>();
```

first set **All element of saved means 0 to files1.size() to FALSE**

**SECOND**

now when in `itemClickListener` set `TRUE at position clicked` in saved
like, `saved.set(position,TRUE);`

and call `notifyDataSetChanged();` in that listenher after setting TRUE at that position.

**THIRD**

now in getView of Adapter Class

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) { 

    View row = convertView; 
    position = = getItemViewType(position);
    if(row==null){ 
        row = LayoutInflater.from(parent.getContext()).inflate(R.layout.row, null); 
    } 

    TextView listTitle = (TextView) row.findViewById(R.id.rowtext); 
    if(saved.get(position)==TRUE)
    {
            listTitle .setTextColor(Color.parseColor("#405478")); 
    }
}
```

and also add this in your adapter class,

```
@Override
public int getItemViewType(int position) {

return position;
}

@Override
public int getViewTypeCount() {
return files1.size();
}
```